# laravel 5 render AccessDeniedHttpException

Tags: laravel, exception

Why is it not rendered in a given way? Other types of exceptions are working well except AccessDeniedHttpException

App/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException as AccessDeniedHttpException;
... 

/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
...
            // 403 Forbidden
            if ($exception instanceof AccessDeniedHttpException)
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'code' => 403,
                    'message' => 'This action is unauthorized1.',
                ],403);
            }
            // 401 Unauthorized
            if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException)
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'code' => 401,
                    'message' => 'Unauthenticated error.',
                ],  401);
            }
```

The 401 is working like a charm, but the 403 do the original rendering.

Any solutions?

Comment: can you paste the full Handle.php file? and where 403 is thrown?

Comment: It is available here becouse its too long:
https://gitlab.com/praad/blogapi/blob/master/app/Exceptions/Handler.php

Comment: I do not throw the error it generates by a framework if i try to update data where the user is not authorized to update it (I use a Postman request for testing).

Comment: so handle this  Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;

Answer (score 14):

Try and include this in your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`. Be sure to add `use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;` at the top of your `Hander.php`:

```
protected $dontReport = [
    \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
];
```

Apparently, `AccessDeniedHttpException` is an instance of `AuthorizationException`.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    //Useful since some methods cannot be accessed in certain URL extensions
    if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class CouponStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;//please change the authorize return to true in request file.
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on what @Josh D. said:

This code worked for me on API:

```
 public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'You don\'t have access to this resource!'
        ],401);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Since for me I couldn't render *Exception* so I had to use *Throwable*.